# getting expression doesn't match error

Tags: binary-search-tree, smlnj, ml

I am trying to implement a node delete function for a Binary Search Tree in SML/nj.
However I am getting a constraint error, that I don't understand why...

```
datatype 'a tree = Empty | Node of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree;
datatype 'a stree = STree of ('a * 'a -> bool) * ('a * 'a -> bool) * 'a tree;

fun removeMin Empty = Empty
  | removeMin (Node(_,Empty,r)) = r
  | removeMin (Node(k,l,r)) = Node(k, removeMin l, r);
removeMin: 'a tree -> 'a tree;

fun get_left_most Empty = Empty
  | get_left_most (Node(k,Empty,r)) = Node(k,Empty,r)
  | get_left_most (Node(_,l,_)) = get_left_most l;
get_left_most: 'a tree -> 'a tree;



fun get_key (Node(k, l, r)) = k;
get_key: 'a tree -> 'a;

fun tree_empty Empty = true
  | tree_empty (Node(_,_,_)) = false;
tree_empty: 'a tree -> bool;



fun remove v (STree(f, g, stree2)) =     
    let
        fun remove2 v Empty = Empty
          | remove2 v (Node(k,l,r)) =
            if f(v, k) then 
                if (tree_empty l) then r
                else if (tree_empty r) then l
                else Node(get_key (get_left_most r), l, removeMin r)
            else if g(v, k) then Node(k, (remove2 v l), r)
            else Node(k, l, remove2 v r);
    in
        STree(f, g, (remove2 v stree2))
    end;
remove: 'a -> 'a stree -> 'a stree;
```

This is the error that I am getting: (for `get_key`)

```
Warning: match nonexhaustive
          Node (k,l,r) => ...
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison using `=` in `remove` means that the tree must contain *equality types* (hence the two `'` characters in the `''Z` type variable that SML inferred) but you have claimed that it's more general: `remove: 'a -> 'a stree -> 'a stree;`.

You need to either only use equality types (i.e. declare `remove: ''a -> ''a stree -> ''a stree;`)
*or* redefine `remove2` to use case analysis instead of comparison.

For instance,

```
| remove2 v (node as Node(k, Empty, Empty)) = if f(v, k) then Empty else node
```

Comment: They are called [equality type variables](http://www.mlton.org/EqualityTypeVariable). More information on polymorphic equality in SML, can be seen [here](http://www.mlton.org/PolymorphicEquality)

Comment: @Jesper.Reenberg Thanks. Amazing what you forget in 15 years... I've updated and hope it's reasonably correct.

Comment: what does this mean: (node @ Node(k, Empty, Empty))

Comment: @omega Sorry, that should be "as" ("@" is the same thing in Haskell).

Comment: ok I got it to work, i updated the code above, but now I am getting a match nonexhaustive for the `get_key` function. How do I return a 'a when it matches Empty? I know it will never match an Empty, but it gives that error if I don't put that match, then I don't know how to return 'a...

Comment: @omega Please post a new question instead of updating.